# set shipping method based on kilometre in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, shipping-methods, table-rates

i am new in learning magento,

my task is i need to implement this,

-Free delivery-within 50km
-table rate shipping-outside of 50km

how to implement this?magento inbuilt functionality provide table rate as per county,region..etc parameter,

but how to implement table rate method with distance?

please help,thanks in advance